# Trying to compare cell values for two row in Google Spreadsheet and increment count if they are equal

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

First time building a custom function for google sheets. I'm trying to compare strings in each cell for two rows and incrementing the value of a cell in a Point column for each cell that is equal. I have the following function done in the script editor:

```
    function tally(a,b) {
  var tally = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if( a[i] == b[i]){
      tally ++;
    }
  }
  return tally;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I figured it out using the following formula:
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(range1,range2))

Answer (score 0):

That function is comparing each cell to the cell directly next to it, linearly.  Is that what you're looking to do?  If you want to compare, for example, the first cell in column A to ever cell in column B, and so on for every cell, you need to use nested 'for' loops.

If this isn't your problem,  can you be more specific about your error?

Comment: i'm trying to compare each cell  lets say range [C3:AA3] to each cell in [$C$25:$AA$25]. I thought the function would work as tally([C3:AA3],[$C$25:$AA$25])

Comment: The idea of incrementing the 'tally' variable is sound, but step through your code and you'll see that you're only comparing a[i] to b[i] - where i is always the same, so you're essentially comparing cell a[1] to b[1] and a[2] to b[2] but never a[2] to b[1]. Does that make sense?  If you use nested 'for loops' i think you'll get what you're after. -- I'd also change the variable name 'tally' from being the same as your function name, for clarity

Comment: I want to only compare a[i] to b[i] because the column is the same. Example I have a column best picture for the golden globes and the a[i] is an entry from a participant but b[i] is the correct answer ( the winning best picture) and then a[2] would be best actress etc...